# How to use Jquery event to trigger window.fbAsyncInit

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to initialize the facebook javascript sdk and check login status after the user clicks a link on my index.html page. For some reason this wont work. The jQuery is working, and when I test the init code separately it works, but when I put it together it stops working. Any idea why?

This is my index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
```

// this jquery is supposed to trigger the init process

```
$('document').ready(function(){
          $('a').click(function(){
             alert("this works");

  // Additional JS functions here
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '39672*******', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//http://spilot.koding.com/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // get login status
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // connected: redirect to start scene page
    alert("testing");
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // not_authorized
    login();
  } else {
    // not_logged_in
    login();
  }
 });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
```

//show login box

```
   function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
            alert("connected");
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    });
}
});
});


</script>





<div id="findScene"><a href=""><h1>Find</h1></a></div>
<div id="startScene"><a href=""><h1>Host</h1></a></div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JS SDK is loaded asynchronously – and it might be finished before the whole page/rest of resources has.

So passing a function to `window.fbAsyncInit` might be to late already – since you are doing it only when `$('document').ready` fires.

Assign the handler function to `window.fbAsyncInit` outside of your `$('document').ready` function.

Comment: I tried assigning 'javascript:window.fbAsyncInit()' to the href in one of the links and it didn't work. Is that what you meant by assigning a handler function outside of the $(document).ready function?

Comment: Why would you want to run this code upon the click on a link? No, you want it to run no matter what as soon as possible – so that the SDK is ready when you want to use it. Just place it _outside_ of the ready-handler, just inside a(n existing) <script> element or external script.

Comment: I want the user to arrive at the home page without immediately being prompted to login or register. I only want that to happen when they click on one of two links on the home page.

Comment: ..but I'll try what you've suggested

Comment: Then load the SDK anyways, and only call FB.login on click.